# How can I do to have a new id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hello I am using Django below is my code :

```
A = myobject.objects.filter(test='a')
A.test= 'b'
A.save()
```

But I noticed when I saved that I have just one query like this :

```
myobject.objects.filter(test='b')
```

Not like this :

```
myobject.objects.filter(test='a')
```

whereas I want both.
Could you help me please ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use get instead of filter while doing this

```
A = myobject.objects.get(test='a')
A.pk = None
A.save()
```

Now you have 2 instances where test='a'. Now you can use filter to update one test to 'b'

```
A = myobject.objects.filter(test='a')[0]
A.test = 'b'
A.save()
```